# What is the maximum size of a page-locked host memory allocation?

Tags: cuda

I'm running CUDA 5.0 on 64-bit Ubuntu 13.04 with an NVIDIA GTS 250 that has 1 GB of memory and NVIDIA driver 319.17. The data set I'm using in my computations is too large to fit on the card itself, so I'm trying to allocate page-locked memory on the host system using `cudaHostAlloc` with the `cudaHostAllocMapped` flag. The data I'm using is about 18 GB in size, and the host has 24 GB of RAM. My problem is that whenever I try to allocate more than 4 GB of page-locked memory, in any number of chunks, I am given the "out of memory" error. With the standard C `malloc` I can allocate the whole 18 GB in one shot, but if I try to map it with `cudaHostRegister` I am still limited to 4 GB.

What is the maximum size of a page-locked allocation in CUDA? Is this a issue in my system or is this limit set by the hardware, the driver, or the CUDA version? Is there any way to allocate such a large array that can be mapped for the GPU?

Comment: I don't think there's some arbitrary CUDA-imposed limit at 4GB.  I'm not sure what the issue is in your case.  I can say that Ubuntu 13.04 is not [an officially supported OS for cuda 5](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#linux), but I don't know if that matters.  I compiled [this simple test program](http://pastebin.com/JBm2nVPu) and ran it on RHEL 5.5 on a server with 48GB of system memory, and I was able to successfully allocate 8GB and 16GB of mapped pinned memory.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: The GTS 250 is a compute 1.1 device - it only has a 32 bit address space. Won't that limit the size of a mapped allocation?

Comment: I believe @talonmies has given the correct answer.  As stated [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory) "Linear memory exists on the device in a 32-bit address space for devices of compute capability 1.x and 40-bit address space of devices of higher compute capability".  So on your cc 1.x device, the host mapped allocation, which must appear in this linear memory space, is limited by the 32bit (4GB) address space.  I was using a cc 2.0 device in my test, which is why I had a higher limit.

Comment: I had read that CUDA 2.2 lifted the 4 GB restriction to pinned memory, but I didn't realize that the device itself has a similar limit. I'll confirm @talonmies answer as correct when the new graphics card I ordered arrives and (hopefully) solves my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SM 1.x class hardware only supports 32-bit addressing.  You might be able to allocate more than 4GB of pinned memory, provided you remove the `cudaHostMapped` flag (and the `cudaDeviceMapHost` flag from `cudaSetDeviceFlags()`).  That would enable you to use asynchronous memory copies to transfer data into and out of GPU memory.

But to *map* more than 4G of memory, you need to use SM 2.x or later, on a 64-bit platform.